# CentOS install proftpd with yum

Tags: centos, yum, centos6, ftp, centos6.2

Server: CentOS 6.2 64bit

How can I install Proftpd using yum? A search for the package doesn't find it:

```
yum list proftpd

Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Although my CentOS 6 VPS does find it, but this server doesn't. I have read I need to install an rpm of some kind. How would I do that and where is the reliable place to get it (64bit)?

I have done Proftpd installs by compiling the source in the past but would prefer to use yum this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install it via EPEL

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/proftpd.html

You can grab the single RPM or install the EPEL repo as follows

```
rpm -ivh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
yum update
yum install proftpd
```

Comment: This worked on the 64bit CentOS, would the same file work on 32bit or would it be a different one?

Comment: it would also work on 32bit.. see the last part of the file.. the noarach part.. means it'll work on 64 or 32 bit. It'll work due it's just a bunch of text files in that package

Answer (score 1):

yum list available proftpd

if you cannot find it, then your repo does not have it.

Comment: It is in the dag repo, or rather rpmforge, it seems, if you cannot find it in your repos. http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-add-the-rpmforge-repository-on-centos-6rhel-6-linux-server/